# App crashes in main after adding delegate protocol; no error code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

In my app, a graph in one view can be dragged to a second view so that the new graph replaces the second view (like a copy/paste effect with a drag and drop feature). The app works if the delegate protocol is taken out so that the second view handles the change in function itself. When the protocol is added, the app crashes in the main file at

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Load_CreatorAppDelegate class]));.
```

There isn't any error output other than the standard (lldb). Even when I take out the call to the delegate (keeping in the code), the app crashes. I know that it has to be related to the protocol code, though, because it worked fine before that.

Here is part of the code for the second view (BeamView):

```
[self drawSupportsAtLeftPoint:self.beamBottomLeft rightPoint:self.beamBottomRight inContext:context :leftPin :rightPin];   

BOOL pt = NO;
if (self.tempLoad) {
    //self.loadGraph = [self.dataSource changeToTempLoad:self]; NOTE #1
    //if (self.tempPtLoad.x != 0 || self.tempPtLoad.y != 0) pt = YES;
    pt = [self changeLoad];
    [self drawLoadWithFunction:self.loadGraph inContext:context fromPoint:self.beamTopLeft toPoint:self.beamTopRight withAlpha:0.3 isPointLoad:pt inBlack:YES];
}
else {
    self.loadGraph = ^(int x) {return x/15;};
    [self drawLoadWithFunction:self.loadGraph inContext:context fromPoint:self.beamTopLeft toPoint:self.beamTopRight withAlpha:1 isPointLoad:pt inBlack:NO];
}

self.tempLoad = NO;
```

NOTE #1: These lines that are commented out are the ones that call on the delegate. Those two methods and their implementation are the only changes I made.

I'm completely confused, any help would be greatly appreciated. What are possible reasons the app will crash in the main file?

Comment: The crash is marking that line as the error because of a mis-feature in Xcode that was introduced with the 4.x series of releases. Basically, an uncaught exception is, by default, not reported until it reaches the top level of your app and then the exception stack trace is not reported.  Sometimes it helps to go to the Breakpoint Inspector and add a break on uncaught Objective-C exceptions; more often it helps to wrap the line from 'main' that you indicated in a @try/@catch and then NSLog the exception's description and callStackSymbols.

Comment: Thanks, @PhillipMills -- I did the following
`@try {
        @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Load_CreatorAppDelegate class]));   
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception); 
        [NSThread callStackSymbols];
    }
`
Is that what you meant? The program is still crashing at the main line and not outputting anything

Comment: Close.  I'd have gone with `@try {
        @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Load_CreatorAppDelegate class]));
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@, Stack: %@", [exception description], [exception callStackSymbols]);}` but if it didn't trigger yours I see no reason for mine to work on it.  The other option would be to move the @try/@catch to where you think the actual error is being generated.

Comment: =/ Alright--thanks so much for your help! I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I feel kind of stupid, but it turned out that the crash didn't have anything to do with delegation (well, kind of). I had deleted outlets in the ViewController.m file without disconnecting them in IB, which was causing the crash.

I'd forgotten that I'd done that, and so it took me a while to think of it--it wasn't until I went back to an older saved version that I saw the differences.